# how to run an iOS simulator that has a control center int it on Xcode 12.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

while debugging on simulators operating on iOS 13.1, 14.4 I can't use the control center of the simulator, it always shows a blank screen when I swipe from top of the screen to bottom.

after some googling, I found some answers suggesting to use simulators operating on **iOS 10.3.1**

I am using Xcode 12.4, and I downloaded simulator 10.3.1 but its not showing in installing list when I try to add additional simulators,

and in Xcode release notes I saw that **Xcode 12.4 supports iOS simulators from 10.3.1 to 14.4**

so my question is:

**how can use a simulator that has a control center in it while developing on Xcode 12.4**

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it. Simulators do not have control center "widgets". You can bring down the control center sheet, which is a good test of what your app does when deactivated; but it is blank, as you say.

I cannot imagine what sort of test you would need actual "widgets" for, but if you want those, test on a device.

Comment: simply...our app should respond differently when we connect device to internet connection (wifi/ mobile data)...or disconnect it, so in android emulators we could simply test it from menu...swipe the menu down...enable connection...disable it...and see how our app responds....this is what I am trying to achieve on iOS simulators

Comment: Well that is what the network link conditioner is for. See for example https://medium.com/macoclock/how-to-simulate-poor-network-conditions-on-ios-simulator-and-iphone-faf35f0da1b5